# Terraform not respecting root module dynamic block if condition's default values

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws

I'm attempting to create a generic dynamodb terraform root module that can handle a few use cases across my org's teams. Some teams will need to create a dynamodb that has a `PAY_PER_REQUEST` billing mode and this db table will also need to have one or more `global_secondary_index` blocks. Rather than creating some "weird" logic around having multiple maps that can hold different settings, I would prefer to handle all of this with some conditional values.

However, Terraform isn't respecting my conditional default values when some other variable is either not set or has a specific value.

I'm currently using this as my provider and terraform version: `hashicorp/aws v5.32.1` and `Terraform v1.4.6`

For example: with a `billing_mode` of `PROVISIONED` the team would need to set the `global_secondary_index` value for `read_capacity` and `write_capacity` where as with a `billing_mode` of `PAY_PER_REQUEST` these values can't be set or at least need a default of `0` after I looked at the `terraform.tfstate`. There's also the matter of when a `projection_type` has a value of `INCLUDE` where the `non_key_attributes` would need to be set otherwise it can't be set or needs to have a default of `[]`, again looking at the `terraform.tfstate` of other currently deployed tables.

So I've created a list of object maps for this in my `variables.tf`.

```yaml
variable "global_secondary_indexes" {
  description = "A list of maps defining global secondary indexes"
  type = list(object({
    name               = string
    hash_key           = string
    range_key          = string
    projection_type    = string
    gsi_read_capacity  = number
    gsi_write_capacity = number
    non_key_attributes = list(string)
  }))
  default = []
}
```

I also tried setting a few of these optional values to `any` so it could handle `null` values.

```yaml
variable "global_secondary_indexes" {
  description = "A list of maps defining global secondary indexes"
  type = list(object({
    name               = string
    hash_key           = string
    range_key          = any
    projection_type    = string
    gsi_read_capacity  = any
    gsi_write_capacity = any
    non_key_attributes = any
  }))
  default = []
}
```

In my `main.tf` I have defined a `dynamic` block as below

```yaml
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "general_dynamodb_table" {
  name             = var.name
  billing_mode     = var.billing_mode
  hash_key         = var.hash_key
  range_key        = var.range_key
  read_capacity    = var.read_capacity
  write_capacity   = var.write_capacity

  dynamic "global_secondary_index" {
    for_each = var.global_secondary_indexes
    content {
      name               = global_secondary_index.value.name
      hash_key           = global_secondary_index.value.hash_key
      range_key          = lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "range_key", "")
      projection_type    = global_secondary_index.value.projection_type
      non_key_attributes = global_secondary_index.value.projection_type == "INCLUDE" ? lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "non_key_attributes", []) : []
      read_capacity      = var.billing_mode == "PROVISIONED" ? lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "gsi_read_capacity", 0) : 0
      write_capacity     = var.billing_mode == "PROVISIONED" ? lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "gsi_write_capacity", 0) : 0
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a test module that I have been using to deploy

```yaml
module "test_dynamodb" {
    source = "../dynamodb"

    name = "test_dynamodb"
    billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
    hash_key = "user_id"

    global_secondary_indexes = [
        {
            name = "my-index-2"
            hash_key = "user_id"
            projection_type = "ALL"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the example where I set the `global_secondary_indexes` block values as `any` I had this as my dynamic block

```yaml
  dynamic "global_secondary_index" {
    for_each = var.global_secondary_indexes
    content {
      name               = global_secondary_index.value.name
      hash_key           = global_secondary_index.value.hash_key
      range_key          = lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "range_key", null)
      projection_type    = global_secondary_index.value.projection_type
      non_key_attributes = global_secondary_index.value.projection_type == "INCLUDE" ? lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "non_key_attributes", []) : null
      read_capacity      = var.billing_mode == "PROVISIONED" ? lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "gsi_read_capacity", null) : null
      write_capacity     = var.billing_mode == "PROVISIONED" ? lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "gsi_write_capacity", null) : null
    }
  }
```

When I try to deploy this module, I receive this error in all attempts

```
 attributes "gsi_read_capacity", "gsi_write_capacity", "non_key_attributes", and "range_key" are required.
```

The `range_key` follows a similar logic that it may not need to be necessarily defined in all circumstances.

Comment: After some playing around, I found that if I changed the variable type to `any` that would work. Needed to make a change to the dynamic block in which I removed the `billing_mode` requirement check in `read_capacity` and `write_capacity` and really just removed the condition entirely in favor of just using a lookup with a default of null. It feels a bit cheaty and I'd still like to know why the conditional isn't respecting the default value or If I'm just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your current configuration all attributes are required, let's do a a smaller example

```hcl
variable "test" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    data = number
  }))
}
```

If we attempt to run with the following
terraform.tfvars

```hcl
test = [
  {
    data = 1
    name = "value"
  },
  {
    name = "foo"
  }
]
```

we get the error:

```txt
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Invalid value for input variable
│ 
│   ...
│ 
│ The given value is not suitable for var.test
| declared at main.tf:1,1-16: element 1: attribute "data" is required.
╵
```

---

We can use the `optional` modifier on the data attribute, that way it is no longer required,
You can read more about it on the official documentation:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#optional-object-type-attributes

Here is a working example, we wrap that number in `optional(...)` and set the default to 0

```hcl
variable "test" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    data = optional(number, 0)
  }))
}

output "test" {
    value = var.test
}
```

that will succeed and show us the following plan:

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + test = [
      + {
          + data = 1
          + name = "value"
        },
      + {
          + data = 0
          + name = "foo"
        },
    ]
```